# Yii Format textField Datetime Model

Tags: php, yii

The `$model->datetime` is `d-m-Y H:i:s`.

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'datetime'); ?>
```

I would like the value of the input just be d-m-Y, how can I format it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to convert the date to a human readable format to display it, and then back to the format needed by the database before you save. You could edit/create the `afterFind()` method in your model to convert the date to a human readable format, something like so:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $this->datetime);
    $this->datetime = $newDate->format('d-m-Y');

    return parent::afterFind();
}
```

And again before you save by editing/creating your model's `beforeSave()` method, for example something like:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $this->datetime);
    $this->datetime = $newDate->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Note that when you save, the hour, minute and second will always be 0 in the examples above. You'd also need to put some validation to make sure your user input was in the correct d-m-Y format too, or the date conversion won't work.

*Fixed typo newdate->newDate

Comment: Remember `DateTime::createFromFormat()` available from PHP 5.3.x